# How to update DB User Credentials via Lambda

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, lambda, amazon-aurora

Appologies if the question is already asked.

I have created aurora postgres database and created a new user on database. I want to manage user credentials in secrets manager and rotate every few months via lambda function. I can generate new password and rotate it in secrets manager using lambda function but I need help to write a python code to update password. Any suggestions please

```
# Setting up connection    
connection_string = f"mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{endpoint}/{db_name}"

# Setting New password
connection_string = connection_string.replace(password,new_password)
```

I tried above but it doesn't update nor give any indication.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have a connection to the underlying database you will have to use a TSQL-command to update the password.

```
ALTER ROLE username   
WITH PASSWORD 'password';
```

See article: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-change-password/

P.S., Do not use the same user that you intend to change, rather use an "administrative" account to perform this action.